# Disable and clear logs and remove event id 1102?

Tags: logging

Can I disable logs and remove event id 1102 (=log cleared event)?
I already tried:

```
Auditpol /set /category:* /success:disable
```

But that didn't work for event 1102!

Comment: This sounds a bit suspicious. Why would you want to clear it?

Comment: Maybe you could ask the owner of the box to do it for you...

Comment: I own the box...

Answer (score 4):

This event ID shows who cleared the security log so its a bit curious as to why you would want to clear it.

You should know the purpose of event logs is to show you things that you may or may not need to look into further.  Microsoft goes out of their way to stop you from deleting pieces.  This helps prevent people from mucking with your system and you having no knowledge at all.  Which when people ask such a question, bad thoughts will be the first thing that comes to mind to anyone intelligent working in IT